# How to keep pandas columns that match a sort?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly large dataframe and I'm trying to reduce it in size. I want to only keep the most recent 'year' per 'Name' in my dataframe. I can sort it but I'm not sure what I can use to remove the other years?

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'year']
```

note, df has more columns but these are the two I'd like to use to use to keep the most recent year.

Is there a way to keep the most recent year? or do I search for the most recent year for each Name and then save it to a new DF?

Comment: Assuming year is numerical: `df.groupby("Name)["year"].max()` is better way to get max year. Then just use `gropuby` and `.loc` to exclude the rows you don't want.

Comment: @noah Thank you df = df.loc[df.groupby("Name")['year'].max()]  worked! if you want to put that as a answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to separate by name, `max` to get the most recent year, and `loc` to select the data. All together:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby("Name")['year'].max()]
```

Comment: actually I think I'm seeing a bug. If the years are not the same. I.e. there is 2020 and 2019, wouldn't this exclude the the 2019 even if it's the highest for "names"?

Comment: It should give you the single highest year for each name. One name's years shouldn't affect another name's years. Is that what you are worried about?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.sort_values('year').drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
```